# how to change font-style and font-size in SVG output from Mathjax-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, mathjax

I would like to set a different font-style and different font-size in SVG output, I am using MathJax-Node for this and I am currently doing this locally without any server, I can create SVG output from MathML as input but unable to set the font side  (sorry I am new to MathJax) also it would be great to know how to scale the SVG output as its not working either

**The input is :**

```
<math style="font-family: Arial;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="math equation" display="inline" altimg-width="467" altimg-height="25" altimg="../images/altmath_5579.png"><mo>⤹</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>Σ</mo><msub><mi>M</mi><mrow><mi>A</mi></mrow></msub><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>;</mo><mspace width="10pt"/><mo>(</mo><mn>900</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">b</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>(</mo><mn>2</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>−</mo><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>F</mi><mrow><mi>B</mi><mi>D</mi></mrow></msub><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">s</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">i</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">n</mi><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>30</mn><mo>°</mo><mo>)</mo><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>10</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo mathvariant="normal">=</mo><mn>0</mn></math>
```

And my JS file is :

```
const fs = require("fs"),
mjAPI = require("mathjax-node"),
svgexport = require('svgexport');
var yourMath;

mjAPI.config ({
  MathJax : {
      SVG : {
          scale: 120,
          font : "STIX-Web",
          undefinedFamily:"'Arial Unicode MS',serif",
          addMMLclasses: true
      }
  },
  displayErrors : true,
  displayMessages : false
});
mjAPI.start();

yourMath = '<math style="font-family: Arial;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="math equation" display="inline" altimg-width="467" altimg-height="25" altimg="../images/altmath_5579.png"><mo>⤹</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>Σ</mo><msub><mi>M</mi><mrow><mi>A</mi></mrow></msub><mo>=</mo><mn>0</mn><mo>;</mo><mspace width="10pt"/><mo>(</mo><mn>900</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">l</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">b</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>(</mo><mn>2</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>−</mo><mo>(</mo><msub><mi>F</mi><mrow><mi>B</mi><mi>D</mi></mrow></msub><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">s</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">i</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">n</mi><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>30</mn><mo>°</mo><mo>)</mo><mspace width="0.33em"/><mn>10</mn><mspace width="0.33em"/><mi mathvariant="normal">f</mi><mi mathvariant="normal">t</mi><mo mathvariant="normal">=</mo><mn>0</mn></math>';

mjAPI.typeset({
  math: yourMath,
  format: "MathML",
  svg:true,
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {
    fs.writeFile("test.svg", data.svg, function(err){
      if(err){
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log('File saved !');
    });
  }

  var mJSON = [{"input":["test.svg"],"output":["123.png"],"quality":["100%"]}];
  svgexport.render(mJSON, function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**So what I need is :**

1. Need to change the font-style in SVG output
2. Need to change the font size in SVG output

Kindly anybody suggest !

**Output:**

[image]

This is the output SVG (**note:** there is no change in the font even after setting font-style in MathML)

Thanks

Comment: I also need to do this (if you work it out let me know)

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. The example works as expected. What are you trying to accomplish? (Though font-style and font-size should be handled in the MathML source and scaling is not necessary with an SVG.)

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks ! but  I have added my output above for your reference kindly check that I didnt get the font change in that (Correct me if wrong) even after setting font-style in MathML

  http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/8VKJg/26/   

in this link the math font change works but not in SVG, Sorry for asking this if bit childish

Comment: Your code indicates that you want to change the font family, i.e., the fontface. That's a very different problem. MathJax (and thus MathJax-node) only supports a handful of math-enabled fonts, http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Peter, now understood